# URLRequest file information pass through

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have this code;

```
function AwesomeFn():void
{
    var filePath:String = "Awesome" + ".swf";
    fileRequest = new URLRequest(filePath);
    fileLoader = new Loader;
    fileLoader.load(fileRequest);
    fileLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadCompleted);
    stage.addChild(fileLoader);
}

function loadCompleted(e:Event)
{
    ...
}
```

---

So my question is: Can *Awesome.swf* know that call is from main swf or standalone run?

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a public function in "Awesome.swf" which you only call in case of loading in a parent-swf.

Or you could add an eventlistener of type `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE` in "Awesome.swf" which will fire only, if "Awesome.swf" is added to a parent-stage.

Comment: I try to find a built-in action actually. I had couple of solutions to move around but as I said before I am looking for a native action.

Comment: The second possibility is a "native build-in feature". Every possible solution to use your "Awesome.swf" as standalone AND added swf will require additional code in "Awesome.swf".

Comment: And it would be not "moving around". Its "core- functionality" ;-)

Comment: You didnt said before "native action"!